# Dynamic addition of broker to a Kafka Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

Can we add more brokers dynamically to Kafka Cluster and achieve Broker fail-over? Don't we get issues with metadata update?

Answer (score 1):

Yes brokers can be added to increase the size of Kafka clusters. However, Kafka does not rebalance partitions onto the new brokers automatically, so this needs to be done manually or via an external tool.

There's a section in the docs that details the steps to expand a cluster: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion

Comment: Thanks... @Mickael Maison will get back to you after trying the same.